# How to transpose parts of data frame in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-preprocessing

I'm quite new to R and especially its use in data preprocessing. I have **data on chemical measurements in the following format:**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample ID | X |  |  |
| Assay Feature | Measure 1 | Value 1 |  |
| Assay Feature | Measure 2 | Value 2 |  |
| Measurement 1 | Molecule 1 | Concentration 1 | Activity 1&2 |
| Measurement 1 | Molecule 2 | Concentration 2 |  |
| Measurement 2 | Molecule 1 | Concentration 3 | Activity 3&4 |
| Measurement 2 | Molecule 2 | Concentration 4 |  |
| Sample ID | Y |  |  |
| Assay Feature | Measure 1 | Value 3 |  |
| Assay Feature | Measure 2 | Value 4 |  |
| Measurement 1 | Molecule 3 | Concentration 5 | Activity 5&6 |
| Measurement 1 | Molecule 4 | Concentration 6 |  |
| Measurement 2 | Molecule 5 | Concentration 7 | Activity 7&8 |
| Measurement 2 | Molecule 6 | Concentration 8 |  |

Which I would like to **convert into:**

| Assay ID | Assay Feature 1 | Assay Feature 2 | Measurement | Molecule A | Molecule B | Concentration A | Concentration B | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Value 1 | Value 2 | 1 | Molecule 1 | Molecule 2 | Concentration 1 | Concentration 2 | Activity 1&2 |
| X | Value 1 | Value 2 | 2 | Molecule 1 | Molecule 2 | Concentration 3 | Concentration 4 | Activity 3&4 |
| Y | Value 3 | Value 4 | 1 | Molecule 3 | Molecule 4 | Concentration 5 | Concentration 6 | Activity 5&6 |
| Y | Value 3 | Value 4 | 2 | Molecule 3 | Molecule 4 | Concentration 7 | Concentration 8 | Activity 7&8 |

I have a good idea how to **match identical measurement numbers into wide format with dplyr**. However, before that I would need to **assign Sample ID and Assay Feature rows into columns** but don't have a good idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that generates the example data?

Comment: Have a look at pivot_wider and pivot_longer from tidyr package

Comment: @geoff I don't have any code yet available. The original format comes as a given text file.

Comment: @gdevaux Thanks, I already did. Conversions into wider and longer are pretty clear. I'm having data in chunks, in each first the assay parameters then the measurements themselves. I think the first issue I have is that I would need to assign this Sample ID to all the rows below until the next Sample ID, which I don't know how to do. In Excel I would just copy paste that and automatize with VBA perhaps.